# How can I make two queries in one?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make this two queries in one ?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `amb_prod` WHERE idAmbiente='".$ambId."';";
$result_set = mysql_query($query);

while($member = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `produto`, `pt` WHERE
        produto.refPT = pt.ref AND
        produto.refPT = $member['idProduto'] ;";
    $result_set2 = mysql_query($query2);
}
```

**I have have tried this but it didn't work..**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `produto`, `pt` WHERE
        produto.refPT = pt.ref AND
        produto.refPT = (SELECT `idProduto` FROM `amb_prod` WHERE idAmbiente='".$ambId.");";
```

Comment: Don't use variable interpolation to create query strings. Rather, use parameterized queries. The former is susceptible to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `produto`, `pt` WHERE
        produto.refPT = pt.ref AND
        produto.refPT IN (SELECT `idProduto` FROM `amb_prod` WHERE idAmbiente='".$ambId.");";
```

I'm not sure about the table structure, but a join may work as well.

Comment: A little off topic, but don't concatenate SQL commands, use parametrized queries if possible (this code is potentially subject to SQL injection).

Comment: If this one get's slow with bigger tables, chech my join solution

Answer (score 2):

With a join instead of subquery:

```
$query = "SELECT pr.*, pt.* 
FROM amb_prod ap 
JOIN producto pr ON (ap.idProduto = pr.refPT) 
JOIN pt ON (pr.refPT = pt.ref) 
WHERE idAmbiente='${ambId}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two cursors open in the same connection the same time. You need to open a second connection. I would strongly advise against that though; issuing a query for every row read would be a bit slow. If I were you, I would do this:

```
SELECT pr.*, pt.*
FROM "produto" pr, "pt" pt, amb_prod ap
WHERE produto.refPT = pt.ref
AND ap.idAmbiente = $ambId
AND produto.refPT = ap.idProduto
```

Ideally, you would convert this to a parametrized query, for [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446551/from-what-do-sql-parameters-protect-you), maintainabilty and performance resons. I'm not sure how it is done in PHP but the [MySQLi_STMT](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) class looks like a good starting point:

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `produto`, `pt` , `amb_prod` WHERE
        produto.refPT = pt.ref AND
        produto.refPT = amb_prod.idProduto
 AND amb_prod.idAmbiente='".$ambId."'  ;

Based on the data, you may have to use distinct in the select clause