# How to query and display matched string from two text boxes in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, where-clause

The following code gets two strings from a text box with id entername and entername1.
The string entered is queried using where clause to match in database and display in list view.
The following code works fine if i dont use a where cause and instead use "select * from text".
Unable to get the output when i use where clause as shown below.
EXAMPLE
OUT PUT:
Test1: Database already contains the entries abc and xyz.
When i enter abc and xyz in respective text boxes and on pressing 'View' i get no output.

```
   package com.example.list;

   import android.R.string;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.Menu;

   import java.util.ArrayList;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity
   {
     SQLiteDatabase mydb;
     TextView name,email;
     Button save,myview;
     ListView lv;
     ArrayList data,data1;
     EditText entername,entername1;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.entername);
   email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.entername1);

   save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bsave);

   //=====CODE FOR SHOWING THE DATA IN TOAST  =======

  lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
    {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(arg2).toString(),3000).show();
    }

 });

 mydb = MainActivity.this.openOrCreateDatabase("androiditu", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY          AUTOINCREMENT,email varchar,name varchar);");

 //=== SAVE BUTTON FOR INSERTING DATA TO DATABASE =======

save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{

public void onClick(View v)
{
 mydb.execSQL("insert into test (name) values(?);",new String[]   {name.getText().toString()});
 mydb.execSQL("insert into test (email) values(?);",new String[]  {email.getText().toString()});

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA INSERTED", 3000).show();

}
});

 myview=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bview);

 data=new ArrayList();
 data1=new ArrayList();

 //=VIEW BUTTON TO SHOW DATA INSERTED IN THE LISTVIEW=======

 myview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {

 public void onClick(View v)
 {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading", 3000).show();
  entername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.entername); 

  entername1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.entername1); 
  String userName=entername.getText().toString(); 
  String userName1=entername1.getText().toString(); 
   Cursor cursor2=mydb.rawQuery("SELECT name,email FROM test where email='"+userName1+"'    and name='"+userName+"'" , null);

  if  (cursor2.moveToFirst())
   {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name’s are:", 3000).show();
     data.clear();
     do
    {

     data.add(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("email")));
     data.add(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("name")));
    }
    while (cursor2.moveToNext());


   //====CODE FOR SHOWING DATA AS A SIMPLE LIST   ITEM=========================================

ArrayAdapter <String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>  (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
  else
  {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA NOT AVAILABLE", 3000).show();
  }
 cursor2.close();
  }
 });
  }
  }
```

Comment: Creating SQL select statements by concatinating using + is a horrible practice. You could as well put your administrator password on your home page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446551

Comment: Basic debugging practice: Take a look in the debugger or add a print statement that shows you how the SQL statement that you send to the server exactly looks like. You can enter this string in the SQL server administrator console and verify what you have to change to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should check the insert into database because i tryed that and for me it gives an error. Try using something like this

INSERT INTO test VALUES (id,'value1','value2');

Id will be null because you autoincrement, value 1 will be the email and value 2 will be the name.