# Creating login screen with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create login screen with WPF, i have input username and password in SQL data base and connected with C# code. When i am designing in visual studio, i am not getting any error messages and everything seams fine, but when i run application and login screen shows up, i put username and password in to fields but i still get error message that information are incorrect but application still let me trough to next window.Bellow is my code in xaml and c#.

```
private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Denis\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Login where Username='" + textBoxUsername + "' and Password='" + textBoxPassowrd + "'", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

    if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
    {
        string username = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"].ToString();
        Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password!", "Paznja", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

    this.Hide();
    MainWindow mn = new MainWindow(); 
    mn.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: What happens if you move the code after the `else` inside the `if` after the `Close();` statement ?

Comment: Are your passwords in plain text in the database?

Comment: @tonyriddle One hurdle at a time, mate ;)

Comment: Just checking to see if that is the cause of the issue :) If they are hashed and he's checking against plain text, it would cause the issue he is describing.

Comment: @tonyriddle very valid point! I think he does seem to mention that it works in a Dev environment... At least that's what I **think** he means by `When i am designing in visual studio, i am not getting any error messages and everything seams fine`..

Comment: I am total beginner in this so please bare with me if i say something wrong :). I have setup database trough Visual Studio 2013 Unlimited and i have create tables and edit rows for username and password.

Answer (score 2):

The following lines are always executed:

```
this.Hide();
MainWindow mn = new MainWindow(); 
mn.Show();
this.Close();
```

Move them into the if statement (that one being executed if the user is found)

Comment: Yes it worked in case of not letting me trough if i don't put correct information(username and password) but application is activating MessageBox.Show("Invalid username and password"); even if i put correct username and password that are setup in database.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct user/pass? :P

Comment: I have put them in database

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
        this.Hide();
        MainWindow mn = new MainWindow(); 
        mn.Show();
        this.Close();
```

**inside** your `if` statement. Putting it after the `else` will make it always run..
PS: You may want to use [SQL Parameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to prevent some nasty [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446551/from-what-do-sql-parameters-protect-you).

Demo:

```
private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Denis\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Login where Username='@Name' and Password='@Pass'", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", textBoxUsername);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Pass", textBoxPassowrd);

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader rdr= cmd.ExecuteReader();

    string username = null; 

    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
           username = rdr["Username"].ToString();
        }

        conn.Close();

        this.Hide();
        MainWindow mn = new MainWindow(); 
        mn.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password!", "Paznja", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is something that would come in handy later, but when i type in username and password that i set up in database it is telling me that is invalid.

Comment: when i add SQL Parameters, and run application. it stops whit running, VS highlights part with adapter.Fill(dataSet) and it says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Comment: I'd go about it using a `SqlDataReader` instead of filling adapters. Check out my update.

Comment: When i changed to SqlDataReader i am getting error message "The type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors defined.

Comment: @Ronin Forgot to add `cmd.ExecuteReader()`. I updated the code.

Comment: when I add cmd.ExecuteReader() i am getting error massage when i start debuging and ArgumentException is trow with message: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArguementException' occured in System.Data.dll" and there id additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Controls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.

Answer (score 1):

```
    this.Hide();
    MainWindow mn = new MainWindow(); 
    mn.Show();
    this.Close();
```

inside your if statement. Putting it after the else will make it always run..