# Error occured when datatype is converted from int to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

    cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=BOPSERVER;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True";
    cn.Open();
    string n = Convert.ToString(txtfid.Text);
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Personal_det where FID=" + n + "";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    da1.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da1.Fill(ds1, "Personal_det");

    double dn = ds1.Tables["Personal_det"].Rows.Count;
    if (dn == 0)
    {
        DateTime sdt = DateTime.Today;
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
        cn.Close();
        cn.Open();
        cmd3.CommandText = "insert into           Personal_det(FID,Name,DOB,MobileNo,EmailId,add1,add2,add3,Pincode) values(@FID,@Name,@DOB,@MobileNo,@EmailId,@add1,@add2,@add3,@Pincode)";
        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd3.Connection = cn;

        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@FID", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
        cmd3.Parameters["@FID"].Value = this.txtfid.Text;

        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd3.Parameters["@Name"].Value = this.txtname.Text;

        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8);
        cmd3.Parameters["@DOB"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtdob.Text);

        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@MobileNo", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18);
        cmd3.Parameters["@MobileNo"].Value = this.txtmbl.Text;

        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@EmailId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd3.Parameters["@EmailId"].Value = this.txtmail.Text;

        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@add1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd3.Parameters["@add1"].Value = this.txtadd1.Text;

        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@add2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd3.Parameters["@add2"].Value = this.txtadd2.Text;

        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@add3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd3.Parameters["@add3"].Value = this.txtadd3.Text;

        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Pincode", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18);
        cmd3.Parameters["@Pincode"].Value = this.txtpin.Text;
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
```

This is my C# code..Actually what i have done is previously i had FID as int now i converted it as varchar(50),because of some needs,i have already changed the datatype in sql..Personal_det is the table where in FID is a primary key constraint and foriegn key for other tables..Now When i am going to execute the code..it gives the error shown in the Image[image: Error in the code]

Comment: Are you sure none of the column names changed when the datatype did? `SELECT * FROM...` is bad form by the way. You almost certainly want to indicate specific fields to be returned.

Comment: @M.Babcock Sorry i didnt get u..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `FID` is string you need to use `''` as below

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Personal_det where FID='" + n + "'";
```

above will avoid your exception but it is not safe

You need to use parameters like you did on second case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491130/is-dynamic-sql-more-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-hacking

Answer (score 2):

Do not create CommandText using strings concatenation - such a bad practice make your sql queries vulnerable for sql-injections.
You can use SqlParameter also for "select" queries, like this.

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Personal_det where FID=@fid";
...
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fid", fidValue))
```