# Incorrect syntax near ',' error in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code in Asp.Net and C#. I am trying to figure out this error from 2 hours but unable to find.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class Result : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;

    string city1, area1, type1, min, max;
    int id;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       city1 = Request.QueryString["city"];
       area1 = Request.QueryString["area"];
       // type1 = Request.QueryString["propertytype"];
       type1= "1bhk";
       min = Request.QueryString["minprice"];
       max = Request.QueryString["maxprice"];
       //  id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["uid"]);
       id = 1;

       con = new SqlConnection("integrated security=true; database=data1; server=sudhir-pc");
       con.Open();

       cmd = new SqlCommand("select price,area,imagename,users_id from property where city='"+city1+"', area='"+area1+"', propertytype='"+type1+"', users_id="+id+"", con);
       //  cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select frstname,laststname,contactno from users where users_id='"+id+"'", con);

       dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       while (dr.Read())
       {
           Label1.Text = (string)dr["price"];
           string area = (string)dr["area"];
           string image = (string)dr["imagename"];
           int id1 = (int)dr["users_id"];
       }
    }
}
```

Error line is `dr=cmd.executereader();`. Same query runs on sql server. can this kind of error be logical?

Comment: If it's a compile error please provide the full error text. If It's a run-time error please provide the full exception message along with inner exceptions and the stack trace.

Comment: I guess, some of the parameters in the QueryStirng may be coming as blank

Comment: no checked that, evrything is der.

Comment: my first thought here is that TSQL is a very specific language, and I believe it expects a space after a comma in a select statement like this.  I don't think select `price,area,imagename`...... without spaces will work.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @marc_s Agreed. Some majorly dangerous code here. The values come straight from the query string.

Comment: or more likely, there is a `,` in one of the variables?  which ties in with @marc_s

Comment: this is my first project in job training. trainer sucks ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace your *comma's* with *and* in your command.So,

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select price,area,imagename,users_id from property where city='"+city1+"', area='"+area1+"', propertytype='"+type1+"', users_id="+id+"", con);
```

would become

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select price,area,imagename,users_id from property where city='"+city1+"' and area='"+area1+"' and propertytype='"+type1+"' and users_id="+id+"", con);
```

A part from that, this is not the way how you should be doing it. You should always use Paremeterized queries. You can read the pros of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412776/benefits-of-use-parameters-instead-of-concatenation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

Comment: same error is coming and pissing me off can it be logical ? bt i dont think so

Comment: Well have you copied it exactly as i have suggested? is user_id an int?

Comment: @user2646803 if your problem solved Mark this answer as useful

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `and` after where condition not comma's

You are in [SQL Injection attack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)..Always use paremeterized queries

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select price,area,imagename,users_id from property where 
                       city=@city1 and area=@area1 and 
                       propertytype=@type1 and users_id=@id", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city1",city1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area1",area1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type1",type1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: sir is that right way to pass information ? querystring ?

Comment: @user2646803 yeah you can use querystring

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this :**

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select price,area,imagename,users_id from property where city=@city and area=@area and propertytype=@proprtytype and users_id=@userid ", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area", area1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@propertytype", type1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", id);

   //  cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select frstname,laststname,contactno from users where users_id='"+id+"'", con);

   dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```