# Validating ---> ' <--- (single quote) exception in c# (preventing SQL Injection)

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, sql-injection

Hi I would like to know how you can stop simple SQL injection by catching the `

> "Unclosed quotation mark" ---> ' <--- error

` when users enter bogus data onto a text box in ASP.NET C#
I would like to know if there is a regular Expression that can be modified to catch all characters except Alphabets as I require to validate a search box which only takes in Alphabets however

> `if a person enters a ---> ' <---` quote mark like this

The whole program crashes with a server side error

If anyone knows a simple expression that can catch this it would be great

Thanks

Comment: Use parametrized queries

Comment: So you are not using [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306668/are-parameters-really-enough-to-prevent-sql-injections?rq=1)?

Comment: Your way of creating/constructing the SQL commands is wrong. You should use a parametrized query/command which prevents SQL injection. EDIT: YES - Three answers at the same time telling the same!

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to access the database?

Comment: sorry I can't help it as I'm working on a complex piece of code which i can do so much to make changes, that's why i'm asking if there's any other way to catch the exception than going through every single bit changing the queries all over again which would take days :(

Comment: simple: `\W` ! will match anything except letters, digits and underscore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to repost AbZy's original comment:

> Use parametrized queries

You responded with:

> sorry I can't help it as I'm working on a complex piece of code which i can do so much to make changes, that's why i'm asking if there's any other way to catch the exception than going through every single bit changing the queries all over again which would take days :(

That's not a good enough reason to avoid doing the work, unless this is an application which you're planning to throw away soon.

If you (or the original authors) write lots of bad code which is vulnerable to SQL injection attack, it will indeed take you a while to fix properly. That doesn't mean you should just try to patch it by detecting "bad" input. Sooner or later someone's going to need to include an apostrophe (e.g. to include a name such as "O'Neill") - at which point you'll have to do more work. At that point you might say "Well I won't *detect* the apostrophe - I'll *escape it*" - which will take you a while to do "mostly correctly" and you'll still end up with a system which is almost certainly vulnerable to attack, but in a more subtle way.

Using parameterized queries is *the* way to fix this. Any time you spend trying to take shortcuts to avoid fixing the problem properly is simply wasted time. Bite the bullet, and do it now. Maybe you need to "down tools" and do nothing else until this is fixed - or maybe you can pick off one query a day to fix, getting on with other features at the same time. Either way, I don't think you should spend any more time just ducking the issue.

Before you respond saying you *can't* go ahead and fix the issue properly, work out what's preventing this, and how you can remove those blockages. Is your management aware of the current risk (which goes well beyond just the server crashing, of course)? Is the problem that you feel you don't have the time to commit to fixing it, or some other obstacle? Is it political or technical? Again, I'd urge you to consider the long term benefit of the application. I've seen *lots* of situations where people have made a short term "hacky" fix and regretted it - but I can't remember ever seeing someone regretting doing the right thing for code which still has a significant period of life left, painful as it can be in the short term.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Jon, really appreciate it. It was a application being developed for testing purposes hence was not going to be on live real time. I would always use parameterised queries when building serious applications however.
Thanks for taking the time to explain the depth of the matter. Really inspiring.

Comment: @Suits999: The thing is, parameterized queries are simpler and *clearer* than building up the SQL too. It's also beneficial to get into good habits even for small apps... you're much less likely to fall into problems like this in production code if you use parameters as a matter of course.

Answer (score 2):

The regex `[A-Za-z]+` matches one or more characters from A to Z (upper or lower case). You may reject a text that doesn't match this regex.

If you want to find all non-alphabet characters, use the regex `[^A-Za-z]` which will match any occurrence of a non-alphabetic character. `Regex.Matches(inputString,"[^A-Za-z]")` gives a `MatchCollection`, every `Match` in which will be for a non-alphabetic character.

[A-Za-z] is a character class allowing any letter and adding `^` immediately after the `[` will match any character other than those specified in the character class.

Comment: Thanks for the help a little manipulation of code you gave helped me to achieve what i was looking for. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Regex pattern (only alphabetical): `(?<=\[)[A-Za-z]+(?=\])`

Use:

`var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\[)[A-Za-z]+(?=\])");`

**EDIT:** Yes, you should use parameterized queries, but in case you want to catch other characters 'real time' just prepare a `TextChanged` event:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Match matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\[)[A-Za-z]+(?=\])")
        if(!matches.Success)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input.", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

So in case one type a non-alphabetical character gets an error message immediately and the textbox is being cleared.

[image]

Comment: You should you use parameterized queries and never try to scape characters

Comment: You are right, I actually use both. He wrote: "I would like to know if there is a regular Expression that can be modified..."

Comment: Thanks for the help Fishmong3r, thats exactly what i wanted to know, not everyone telling me that i need to use parameterized queries. I know that, I'm in the process of editing a part of an existing piece of code which i can't manipulate fully thats why.

Comment: i could but i'm getting an error near `input` field any idea why?

Comment: I should see your code to help you further. Anyway you asked for a regex pattern.

Comment: Seriously, the above code is tested, and working fine. Please let us know what error you receive, also post the related code. Offering bounty is nice, but without more information it won't solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

this will work i used in my applycations many times
**it's c# WPF tested**

```
   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;
        //allowed char's are 0-9, a-z, A-Z, germanChars, '-' and as extra the {0,40} part where you are able to define the Min and Max Char's
        var matches = Regex.Matches(tb.Text, @"^[0-9a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜß''-'\s]{0,40}$");
        if (!(matches.Count > 0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input.", "Text", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always remove unnecessary characters from the input, leaving only the ones you allow. I created a simple class with a couple of methods that I used in one of my apps.

```
public static string ToLettersAndDigits(this string text)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in text)
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            sb.Append(c);

    return sb.ToString().Trim();
}

public static string ToLetters(this string text)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in text)
        if (char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            sb.Append(c);

    return sb.ToString().Trim();
}

public static string ToDigits(this string text)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in text)
        if (char.IsDigit(c))
            sb.Append(c);

    return sb.ToString().Trim();
}
```

It checks every char for a valid input, if it is invalid, it does not add it to the StringBuilder. It would probably be best on fields like "Name", where you do not have thouthands of charachters. 
Once you have this class, you can simply write `resultString = yourString.ToLetters()` and you will end up with only letters. Not the most elegant solution but it works!

EDIT:
You can also add punctuation,

```
foreach (char c in text)
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '!')
            sb.Append(c);
```

Comment: Also, check out AJAX FilteredTextBoxExtender. It is not that difficult to work around it if one is determined to use SQL Injection against you but it will definitely prevent an accidental injection from a user... http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx