# C# update and set of database (datediff) don't work when in C# but works if in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have searched for solutions but I can't find one; please help.

I have this code fragment in C#:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
{
    command.Connection = openCon;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "update logRecords set totalHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,timeIn,timeOut)";

    try
    {
        openCon.Open();
        int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Records affected: " + recordsAffected);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
         openCon.Close();
         GetLogData();
     }
}
```

but it doesn't work. It didn't show the message box in the try block neither the one in the catch block.

Thanks for helping :D

Comment: you didn't specify the `where` clause, it will update whole table

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Comment: Have you try to run in debug mode?

Comment: @jenel Instead of text command, I will create Stored Procedure to update logrecords..

Comment: Can you show please the declaring part of `openCon`?

Comment: I'm assuming that the `openCon` is `SqlConnection`, so you don't need to use `finally` block, just add it into `using` block. `SqlCommand`'s `CommandType` is `Text` by default.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that's what i want to do, to update all the records in my table.

Comment: @SeM this is the declaration part of openCon

 SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=dbSample; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");

Comment: What kind of application is this? Webapplication does not show message box.

Comment: i have other update queries in my code and they all worked well, that's the only query that doesn't work

Comment: what exactly is a Stored Procedure sir @Bharat ?

Comment: C# windows form sir @Amit

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see if it is even running? Have you put a breakpoint in the code?

Comment: @JenelGomez: first thing, don't call sir, second thing, whatever you right overhere will come to SP. "command.CommandText = "update logRecords set totalHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,timeIn,timeOut)"; "

Comment: Do you want SP based Solution?

Comment: @Bharat i'm sorry for that. :) thank you :D i'll try it now. :D

Comment: @Bharat how is that? yes please?

Comment: What is the DataType of timeIn and timeOut ?

Comment: ok..wait for few minutes.

Comment: @JenelGomez Your code is fine. I checked with a proper connection string.

Comment: @RojalinSahoo their data types are both Time

Comment: @Bharat thank you very much! :D

Comment: I fill the problem is  with  `DATEDIFF(HOUR,timeIn,timeOut)`. You can Try to run the query with some value through sql server then try it out with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access query with parameters, hope this help:

```
using(var openCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
{
    command.Connection = openCon;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "update logRecords set totalHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,@timeIn,@timeOut)";

    try
    {
        openCon.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeIN", timeIn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeOut", timeOut);
        int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Records affected: " + recordsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    GetLogData();
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer, but downvotes: 1. random indenting; 2. not using a `using` block.

Comment: AddWithValue has [performance implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263536/addwithvalue-sql-injection-safe-why).

Answer (score -1):

First of all I will create Stored procedure and I will update any of my table through procedure.

So, Basic SP will be like below, and I will run it in a Database(SQL).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Set_LogRecords_TotalHours
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @timeIn     datetime,
    @timeOut    datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE  LogRecords 
    SET     TotalHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @timeIn, @timeOut)

    -- returns number of rows
    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
END
GO
```

Now, I will Move to code side.

I will Create a Generic method to call All of mine Stored procedures, see below.

```
public static DataSet GetRecordWithExtendedTimeOut(string SPName, params SqlParameter[] SqlPrms)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            //here give reference of your connection and that is "openCon"
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SPName, conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddRange(SqlPrms);
                    command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    conn.Open();
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {                                
                            return null;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle Errror
        }

        return ds;          
    }
```

Now at last, call this method from wherever you need to access database.

Over here is the example of calling generic method.

```
    //Add all the parameter that you want to pass to SP, here we have 2 and they are in DAteTime Formate
SqlParameter[] parameters = 
                    {
                        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@timeIn", Value = ValueOf_TimeIN_DateTIME }
                        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@timeOut", Value = ValueOf_TimeOUT__DateTIME}
                    };

DataSet ds = DAL.GetRecordWithExtendedTimeOut("Set_LogRecords_TotalHours", parameters);

if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count >= 1 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >= 1)
{
    //Debugg ds and you will see the number of records that affected in last update
}
```

Comment: What's the point in wrapping such a simple single statement in a stored proc (I know some places have "only stored procedure" rules, but that's about DBAs having control issues.)

Comment: @Richard : only one, She needs to understand the SP based framework, check comments in question part..it can be helpfull for other SO..

Comment: SProcs only came up when you suggested them ("what exactly is a Stored Procedure").

Comment: @Richard, Yes, that's true, but what I think is that SO is new, and she didn't even know about SP, and that's why I created that much mesh, I also know that Issue is in the parameters that she is passing but she can't check it because of inline query. maybe my answer can explain her   a way of ADO.Net working pattern..

Comment: You're really just confusing absolutely everything by suggesting a stored proc when there was no need to. Stored Procs aren't magic solutions. Also, this catching an exception and returning null business is just gross.