# How can I write a command to select a data from a database table when it matches the input provided on my textBox1.text?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am working on a windows app that will display the **Synonym** to a **TextBox2** if the input on **TextBox1** matches any of the data in the **Word** column of my database table below. My code below only output **Joyful** when I enter any of the words in **Word** column
Please how can I correct & achieve that?

See my table and code below:

```
**Id**  **Word**    **Synonym**
1   Happy   Joyful
2   Sad     Unhappy
3.  Good    Fine


string constr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=…\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Synonym FROM Ant&Syn WHERE Id = 1"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        sdr.Read();
                        textBox2.Text = sdr["Synonym"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
```

Comment: _WHERE Id = 1_ this will retrieve always the same record. You need to change this condition to use the string present in the Textbox. Search how to use the WHERE statement in sql

Comment: @Steve, Thank you for spotting that. I will read more on how to use the WHERE statement in sql

Comment: @OlivierRogier, Thank you for referring me to that link. The post is helpful. However, I tried this: SELECT Synonym FROM Ant&Syn WHERE Word = '" + TextBox1 + "'" did not work. Do you have a better suggestion for me. I am new here. still learning

Comment: The accepted answer contains an error as well your original code. You are calling Read but you don't care what is the result of that Read. If there is no matching record then there is nothing to read and the call return false. You shouldn't blindly try to extract values from a reader when Read return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using parameterized query as below?

```
string matchingWord = TextBox1.text;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Synonym FROM Ant&Syn WHERE Word = @word"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", matchingWord)
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        sdr.Read();
                        textBox2.Text = sdr["Synonym"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My program seems to be working as expected now after following your suggestion above.

Comment: Using `AddWithValue` is not recommended: [AddWithValue sql injection safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263536/addwithvalue-sql-injection-safe-why/21263886) and [SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for sharing this side information about the use of AddWithValue. Very useful. A lot to learn and discover in the world of programming

Answer (score 0):

**Using a SQL parameter**

It execute the query to filter on the word to search and returns all available synonyms `0..*` using the generic [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) class to store values that will be joined for a one line display in the text box (empty string if none found):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

```
var synonyms = new List<string>();

using ( var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) )
  try
  {
    connection.Open();
    using ( var command = connection.CreateCommand() )
    {
      command.CommandText = "SELECT Synonym FROM [Ant&Syn] WHERE Word = ?";
      command.Parameters.Add("@word", SqlDbType.Text).Value = TextBox1.text;
      using ( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() )
        while ( reader.Read() )
          synonyms.Add(reader[0].ToString());
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    connection.Close();
  }

TextBox2.Text = string.Join(", ", synonyms);
```

We can manage multiple results with a multi-line textbox, a listbox, a context menu or anything else.

[What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

[AddWithValue sql injection safe? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263536/addwithvalue-sql-injection-safe-why/21263886)

[SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

**Output**

```html
Fine
```

**Improvement - Refactoring**

We can create a method and use the [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) keyword to return a [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1):

```
IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word)
{
  using ( var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) )
    try
    {
      connection.Open();
      using ( var command = connection.CreateCommand() )
      {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Synonym FROM [Ant&Syn] WHERE Word = ?";
        command.Parameters.Add("@word", SqlDbType.Text).Value = word;
        using ( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() )
          while ( reader.Read() )
            yield return reader[0].ToString();
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      connection.Close();
    }
}
```

```
var synonyms = GetSynonyms(TextBox1.text);
```

**Improvement - Case insensitive comparison**

We can use a flag to set the option:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetSynonyms(string word, bool caseInsensitive)
{
  using ( var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) )
    try
    {
      connection.Open();
      using ( var command = connection.CreateCommand() )
      {
        string checkColumn = caseInsensitive ? "lower(Word)" : "Word";
        string checkMatch = caseInsensitive ? word.ToLower() : word;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Synonym FROM [Ant&Syn] WHERE " + checkColumn + " = ?";
        command.Parameters.Add("@word", DbType.String).Value = checkMatch;
        using ( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() )
          while ( reader.Read() )
            yield return reader[0].ToString();
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much too. I have saved it for later testing. I hope it works with LocalDB in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier, am really new & still learning. So please be patient with me. I tried your code and I am having the following two errors below:
First error is: "The name 'Builder' does not exist in the current context". 
Secondly error is: "The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"