# how to save string variable with apostrophe using .net

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I have a query like this:

```
sql = "Select * From T_ExhibitorLocation 
        where F_ExhibitionCode='" & Cmb_Exhibition.SelectedValue.ToString & "' 
          and F_ExhibitorCode='" & Trim(Txt_ExhibitorID.Text) & "' 
          and F_Site='" & cmb_Site.SelectedValue.ToString &` "'"
```

Some time my F_site name come with apostrophe,
example like this  **`'Artist's Shell'`**. So this time how I can save this name with apostrophe ?? thanks in advance

Comment: Dont build sql that way.  Use SQL Parameters and the SQL will be more readable and problems with ticks will vanish.

Comment: Plus SQL parameters will [prevent sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/306675/106866)

Answer (score 2):

Like Pluntonix said in his comment always try to avoid building sql command in this way..try the below way if you can

```
var command = new SqlCommand("Select * From T_ExhibitorLocation 
        where F_ExhibitionCode=@Cmbexhibition 
          and F_ExhibitorCode=@exhibitioncode
          and F_Site=@site");
SqlParameter param1  = new SqlParameter();
param1.ParameterName = "@Cmbexhibition";
param1.Value         = Cmb_Exhibition.SelectedValue.ToString();

SqlParameter param2  = new SqlParameter();
param2.ParameterName = "@exhibitioncode";
param2.Value         = Trim(Txt_ExhibitorID.Text);

SqlParameter param3  = new SqlParameter();
para3.ParameterName = "@site";
param3.Value         =cmb_Site.SelectedValue.ToString();

command.Parameters.Add(param1);
command.Parameters.Add(param2);
command.Parameters.Add(param3);
```

Then execute it.

Comment: I would rather create typed parameters